# Get value for current user from Firebase Firestore - Swift 4

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

this is my first question here, i hope you can help me.

I've been trying to get a specific path for the current user logged into my app.

I don't really now what i'm doing wrong so i'll paste my code here.

```swift
func userRoleListener() {

guard let user = Auth.auth().currentUser else { return } . 
Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document("sjbD5SvKTYHWBLhCqojs").getDocument { (snapshot, error) in
 if let data = snapshot?.data() {
 guard let isAdmin = data["isAdmin"] as? Bool else { return }
   if isAdmin {
    self.applyButton.isHidden = true
   } else {
     self.applyButton.isHidden = false
   }
  }
 }
}
```

This is my function to create a user.

```
private func createUser() {

        guard let nameAndLastname = nameAndLastnameTextField.text , let email = emailTextField.text , let password = passwordTextField.text , !nameAndLastname.isEmpty , !email.isEmpty , !password.isEmpty else {
            simpleAlert(title: "Error", msg: "Debe completar todos los campos")
            return

        }

        let newUserReference = Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document()

        newUserReference.setData([
            "nameAndLastname": nameAndLastname,
            "email": email,
            "password": password,
            "isAdmin": false,
            "timestamp": Timestamp()
            ])
    }
```

And this is my login action:

```
@IBAction func signUpButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

        guard let email = emailTextField.text , let password = passwordTextField.text , !email.isEmpty , !password.isEmpty else { return }

        self.signUpButton.animateButton(shouldLoad: true, withMessage: "")

        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, error) in
            if let error = error {
                self.signUpButton.animateButton(shouldLoad: false, withMessage: "¡REGISTRAR!")
                debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
                self.simpleAlert(title: "Error", msg: "Error al iniciar sesión, intente nuevamente en unos minutos")
                return
            }

            self.signUpButton.animateButton(shouldLoad: false, withMessage: "")
            self.createUser()
            self.presentClientStoryboard()

        }

    }
```

And this is an image of my database:

[Database image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hv4sf.png)

Comment: What is going wrong when you run this code?

Comment: The issue i'm having is when i try this:

Firestore.firestore.collection("users").document(user.uid).getDocument()

I don't receibe any current user, but when i go straight forward and insert manually the current userd id ("sjbD5SvKTYHWBLhCqojs"), the button is hidden and also get the data form Firestore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create a user with Firebase Authentication, Authentication will create a user and a user id for you in Firebase Auth (Not Firestore)

So when you create your user in Firestore, you have to set the userID as document id, like below:

```
@IBAction func signUpButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    guard let email = emailTextField.text , let password = passwordTextField.text , !email.isEmpty , !password.isEmpty else { return }

    self.signUpButton.animateButton(shouldLoad: true, withMessage: "")

    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, error) in
        if let error = error {
            self.signUpButton.animateButton(shouldLoad: false, withMessage: "¡REGISTRAR!")
            debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
            self.simpleAlert(title: "Error", msg: "Error al iniciar sesión, intente nuevamente en unos minutos")
            return
        }

        self.signUpButton.animateButton(shouldLoad: false, withMessage: "")
        self.createUser(user.uid)       // <----- user id from Firebase Auth
        self.presentClientStoryboard()

    }

}
```

and

```
private func createUser(userId: String) {

    guard let nameAndLastname = nameAndLastnameTextField.text , let email = emailTextField.text , let password = passwordTextField.text , !nameAndLastname.isEmpty , !email.isEmpty , !password.isEmpty else {
        simpleAlert(title: "Error", msg: "Debe completar todos los campos")
        return

    }

    let newUserReference = Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(userId)    // <-- create a document, with the user id from Firebase Auth

    newUserReference.setData([
        "nameAndLastname": nameAndLastname,
        "email": email,
        "password": password,
        "isAdmin": false,
        "timestamp": Timestamp()
        ])
}
```

Comment: This one worked, i didn't know that i have to pass the userid on the create action. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

**You should get the user id from the current user, try this:**

```
func userRoleListener() {

guard let userUid = Auth.auth().currentUser.uid else { return } . 
Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(userUid).getDocument { (snapshot, error) in
 if let data = snapshot?.data() {
 guard let isAdmin = data["isAdmin"] as? Bool else { return }
   if isAdmin {
// And I believe here the true and false values should be switched as you are checking if the user IS an admin, if they are an admin, shouldn't you show the button?
    self.applyButton.isHidden = false
   } else {
     self.applyButton.isHidden = true
   }
  }
 }
}
```

This get's the current user logged into the app and then uses the users uid to search the database. Just make sure when you create an account you save the user data accordingly.

Comment: I've tried this before, and i have the same issue, it didn't work.

Comment: Can you please update your code with when a user signs up, and maybe also a photo of your database?

Comment: Yes and using the answer above you can get the current user information with my answer. Hope you found the code easy to read and understandable.